# Whats wrong with my ps4

Tags: ps4

My boyfriends sent his ps4 into Sony for an internal memory corrupt and he got it back today but it won't turn on it beeps when you press the button but won't turn on. He checked all the cords and they were all correct an all, he unplugged it and plugged it back in after a fewinutes he tried everything but it just beeps and doesn't turn on did Sony even try to do anything?

Comment: Your best bet is to reach out to them again.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the firmware on the PS4 has been removed. You can try to re-install it using the [PS4 Recovery Menu](http://www.xtremeps3.com/2014/11/02/tutorial-how-to-access-the-ps4-recovery-menu-safe-mode/) and a USB drive.

You can access the Recovery Menu as follows:

1. Turn off the PlayStation 4 completely. Do not use in Stand-by / Rest
   mode.
2. Once the PlayStation 4 is off, press and hold the power button.
   Release it after you’ve heard two beeps: one when you initially
   press, and another 7 seconds later.
3. Connect the DualShock 4 controller with the provided USB cable and
   press the PS button on the controller.

From the Recovery Menu, you need to choose Option 7: "Initialize PS4 (Reinstall System Software)". But note that this will delete all the data on your PS4 (if any still exists).

[Instructions on loading a USB drive with the update file can be found here](https://www.playstation.com/en-us/support/system-updates/ps4/#newinstallation).